# After an Airdrop, should I check the photos for corruption?

Tags: file-sharing, file-transfer, airdrop

If something goes wrong during an Airdrop, say from my iPhone to my Macbook, how can I check for any corruption?

Would simply checking that the photos, videos, etc. can be opened be enough to confirm there is no corruption?

Or, for example, would I have to watch the whole video file to make sure there's no corruption in it?

Comment: No, you'd compute a CRC/SHASUM and verify the file on both sides had the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You generally shouldn't need to check for this, as corruption is extremely unlikely if the transfer is successful.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirDrop):

> AirDrop uses TLS encryption over a direct Apple-created peer-to-peer Wi-Fi connection for transferring files.

While TLS is not specifically intended as an error-detection method, it will effectively act as one, because if anything is corrupted in transit the decryption will almost certainly fail.

In addition, WiFi has CRC error detection at the link layer.

The only kind of corruption that might get around these checks are if they happen at one of the endpoints when reading/writing the file, not in transit. That same kind of problem could occur if you're simply copying a file on the same machine, it's not related to AirDrop.